# How to visualize results/errors of multilabel classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, visualization, multilabel-classification

For **multiclass** classification you would normally choose a confusion matrix to plot the error of predicted classes against the target classes.

What is the best way to visualize errors of **multilabel** classifiers? As multiple classes are predicted at once a mapping of prediction against target is not always possible so confusion matrices are generelly not suitable.

My first idea is to plot a bar chart where each class has a bar for missed and one for false predictions. But is there any standard for visualizing the errors which includes more information just like a confusion matrix for multiclass problems?

Answer (score 1):

There is something called macro-averaging and micro-averaging.

Macro-averaging is just the TPs, TNs, FPs, and FNs of each label class summed up and averaged. You should use macro-averaging for generalizing and evaluating on the overall. You should not use it to make specific decisions.

See details of micro-averaging and more evaluation techniques in the link below. 
https://towardsdatascience.com/journey-to-the-center-of-multi-label-classification-384c40229bff#6aaa

Comment: Yes, that should give a little impression of the performance of the classifier. To extend this a little further one can also add a few more stats to the matrix like accuracy, false discovery rate and so on: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score#Diagnostic_testing

Answer (score 0):

I found [classification_report](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) to be extremely helpful in understanding how my model is doing for each label. It generates a report detailing the f1-score, recall and precision for each label.